# How did the author find the vector v prime perpendicular to n

Tags: matrices, vectors, 3d, linear-transformations

I'm reading the $3D$ Math Primer for Graphics and Game Development by Fletcher Dunn and Ian Parberry, but I've gotten stuck.

If you look at the attached image where it says, "Now we can see the portion of $v$ prime perpendicular to $n$ is given by: .."

How does "$\cos(\theta v_{\perp}) + \sin(\theta w) = v'_{\perp}$"?

Do let me know, if additional information is needed.

[image]

Comment: That should be $cos(θ)v_⊥ + sin(θ)w = v′_⊥$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may help to consider the 2D case. To keep things simpler, I'll use $\mathbf{v}$ in place of $\mathbf{v_\perp}$

Let $\mathbf{v} = (r \cos\alpha, r \sin\alpha)$

**w** is obtained by rotating **v** around the origin by 90°, so

$\mathbf{w} = (-r \sin\alpha, r \cos\alpha)$

Now, we rotate **v** by $\theta$ to obtain **v'**, so

$$\begin{align} 
\mathbf{v^\prime} & = (r\cos(\alpha + \theta), r\sin(\alpha + \theta)) \\
 & = (r\cos\alpha\cos\theta - r\sin\alpha\sin\theta, r\sin\alpha\cos\theta + \cos\alpha\sin\theta) \\
 & = \cos\theta(r\cos\alpha, r\sin\alpha) + \sin\theta(-r\sin\alpha, r\cos\alpha) \\
\mathbf{v^\prime} & = \cos\theta\mathbf{v} + \sin\theta\mathbf{w}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Great answer! It makes a lot more sense. The only surprise I had was the line $$\begin{align}
& =(r\cos\alpha\cos\theta - r\sin\alpha\sin\theta, r\sin\alpha\cos\theta + \cos\alpha\sin\theta) \\
 & =\cos\theta(r\cos\alpha, r\sin\alpha) + \sin\theta(-r\sin\alpha, r\cos\alpha) \\
\end{align}$$ I don't remember doing algebra arithmetic between two points (when there is a comma in between). Do you know what that is called? I'd like to read more about it.

Comment: @conman: Sorry, I don't know if that has a special name. It's just an application of addition of two vectors, and multiplication of a vector by a scalar. I guess it's a bit easier to go from the 2nd line to the 1st than the other way around, but that sort of thing becomes obvious once you get used to doing algebra with vectors in component form.

Comment: FWIW, I haven't really played with this stuff for a few decades - I normally let my software handle the messy details. :) I like to do 3D rendering using the venerable (and free) program, [POV-Ray](http://www.povray.org/). Unlike more modern 3D systems, POV-Ray doesn't have a GUI - you create 3D objects & scenes using a special programming language, so it does help to have some familiarity with vector arithmetic / algebra when using POV-Ray.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying, it is indeed easier to go from the second line to first. Thanks for sharing the link, I'll look into that. It might help me get a better intuition of what I'm learning.